# Custom type serializer for Json.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I'm using NewtonSoft Json.Net to serialize my objects to JSON. On of my classes is not serializing correctly. I was wondering if it is possible to build a custom type serializer that will output different JSON.

How can I make a custom serializer/deserializer for a specific class?

Comment: If you can provide more details about your class and what the JSON needs to look like, I'd be happy to provide a specific example.  Otherwise, you can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18668617/10263), which demonstrates how to get around problems when serializing/deserializing the `IPAddress` and `IPEndpoint` classes.  That may be enough to get you started.

Comment: @BrianRogers, thanks, but the answer of Dmytro helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may create your own [Custom JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and implement its ReadJson and WriteJson methods.