# How to Convert a datetime to a customise typed object with NewtonJson.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

e.g.

i got a class named Person:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
}
```

and i want to convert this object to a customer json string like this
`{
   "Name":"Tom",
   "Birth":{"Year":1999,"Month":12,"Day":1}
}`

Comment: You can use a view model to achieve that

Comment: a little bit of googling can help a lot. Take a [look](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom type serializer for Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140472/custom-type-serializer-for-json-net)

Answer (score 0):

declare two class:

```
public class BirthDay
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BirthDay Birth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want an additional class, you can achieve this by returning an `object`

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public DateTime BirthDateTime { get; set; }
   public object Birth => new {
       Year = BirthDateTime.Year,
       Month = BirthDateTime.Month,
       Day = BirthDateTime.Day,
   };
}
```

Also you'll have to add the `[JsonIgnore]` over the `DateTime` property if you don't want it serialized:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public DateTime BirthDateTime { get; set; }
```

I would recommend this method only if the class is used **only as a DTO**